# how to write post loop code in a wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, portfolio

I have a html theme and and want to convert it to a wordpress theme,
the project section in this theme will shown post and have a special structure,
my problem is writing a php & wordpress function which could show with same appearance and also get post from admin panel , i.e. make it dynamic
for getting problem clear please look at the attachment [link](https://hotfile.com/dl/236584608/b7f870b/htmls.zip.html) which contains the html theme, I think it could be done by a while loop. Can someone help me out in writing this.

Here is the project section code , which we want to turn it into a php code :

```
<div id="home-presentation" class="custom-scroll">
        <div class="list">
            <div class="box">               

                <div class="fly first">
                    <h4><a href="portfolio.html">Projects</a></h4>
                </div>

                <div class="el_3 pos_3 fly big color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/10/presentation.jpg" alt="backgrounds" > 
                        <span>
                        backgrounds
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_3 pos_7 fly without-image color_1">
                    <div class="project">
                    <span class="arrow top">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">backgrounds</a></h5>
                    <p>Project: backgrounds</p>
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_5 pos_8 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                    <img src="images/temp/presentations/60/presentation.jpg" alt="last one" > 
                    <span>
                    and last
                    </span>
                    <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="box">

                <div class="el_8 pos_1 fly big color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/58/presentation.jpg" alt="customer 3" > 
                        <span>
                        customer 3
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_6 pos_5 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/54/presentation.jpg" alt="customer 1" > 
                        <span>
                        customer 1
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_6 pos_6 fly without-image color_3">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow left">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">customer 1</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: customer 1</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_5 pos_7 fly without-image color_3">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow left">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">last one</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: last one</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_9 pos_8 fly without-image color_1">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow right">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">customer 4</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: customer 4</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="el_8 pos_1 fly without-image color_1">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow left">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">customer 3</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: customer 3</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_7 pos_2 fly without-image color_3">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow right">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">customer 2</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: customer 2</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_10 pos_3 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/63/presentation.jpg" alt="customer 5" > 
                        <span>
                        customer 5
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_10 pos_4 fly without-image color_1">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow left">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">customer 5</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: customer 5</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_9 pos_5 fly big color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/62/presentation.jpg" alt="customer 4" > 
                        <span>
                        customer 4
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="el_7 pos_1 fly big color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/65/presentation.jpg" alt="customer 2" > 
                        <span>
                        customer 2
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_4 pos_5 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/48/presentation.jpg" alt="free and safe" > 
                        <span>
                        free and safe
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_4 pos_6 fly without-image color_3">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow left">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">free and safe</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: free and safe</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_5 pos_7 fly without-image color_3">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow right">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">last one</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: last one</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_5 pos_8 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/50/presentation.jpg" alt="last one" > 
                        <span>
                        last one
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="box">               

                <div class="fly last">
                <p><a href="http://dev.creativex.bg/svn/vladi/CreativeX/bg/portfolio/">Всички</a></p>

                <h6><a href="http://dev.creativex.bg/svn/vladi/CreativeX/bg/portfolio/"><span>453</span>Projectа</a></h6>
                </div>

                <div class="el_3 pos_1 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/46/presentation.jpg" alt="backgrounds" > 
                        <span>
                        background image
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_3 pos_2 fly without-image color_1">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow left">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">backgrounds</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: background image</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_2 pos_3 fly without-image color_1">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow right">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">test 2</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: test 2</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="el_2 pos_4 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/70/presentation.jpg" alt="test 2" > 
                        <span>
                        test 2
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_1 pos_5 fly color_1">
                    <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="image">
                        <img src="images/temp/presentations/71/presentation.jpg" alt="testovi danni" > 
                        <span>
                        testovi danni
                        </span>
                        <ins></ins>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="el_1 pos_6 fly without-image color_3">
                    <div class="project">
                        <span class="arrow left">&nbsp;</span><h5><a href="javascript:;">testovi danni</a></h5>
                        <p>Project: testovi danni</p>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="details" title="view details">view details</a>
                        <a href="portfolio_view.html" class="live" title="go live">go live</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $vik=1  query_post('showposts');

  while(have_posts()): the_post();
  ?>
   <li class="test<?php echo $vik; ?>">
   <?php the_title();
    the_content()
    the_permalink();
     ?>
    </li>
   <?php 
  $vik++;
endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Try to use the following or follow the wordpress  codex function rule  hope  this will help you to make dynamic posts

Comment: thnx, i knew this structure, but if you see above , each post has a custom class in this way: pos_{a number variable} and el_{a number variable},, how to define a variable to use correct number, because this numbers are important and javascript use it to make a layout  which you can see in the attachement, How do that?

Comment: ok i checked you code  but  when you pass the loop you need to pass a variable in you class which will auto increment  like  1,2,3  with you class  after that  you have to set the  css for perticular class like   .class1 {color:this } .class2{color this} and folow

Comment: this classes hast defined in css, but are you sure variable should be use auto increment , because numbers seems dont obey a regular method, could you give me a proper code for test? thnx for your help

Comment: your case on every post there is different color  so you need to pass the custom css for every posts  variable will get  auto incremented  i uodated the sample code  you need to write the css for every post box which you want to format

Comment: yeah ,i got it, but there is another problem, in this code,each div with "box" class contains 2 or 3 or 4 post, and the numbers of post in each box is different, how loop <div class"box"></div> , this div is very important , becuase horizental scrolling just work when this div is included, what your idea,bro?

Comment: yeah sorry forgot to close li  have you close you  div  properliy in loop or out side